# Only some Winston logger.error calls appear in the GCP error reporting

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, winston, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm using Winston in my Node.js application on GCP as described here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-winston-quickstart
That works in a sense that I see the logs I expect in the log explorer.

I now want to that all errors appear in the "Error Reporting" dashboard (https://console.cloud.google.com/errors?project=...).
However, only some errors are listed there. I am not 100% sure which errors make it to the error reporting dashboard, but my suspicion is that `logger.error` calls only appear in the error dashboard if there's a proper error stack trace.

But that's not what I want. I want that whenever `logger.error` in my application is triggered, an error group on the error reporting dashboard should be created - regardless of the string I pass to `logger.error`.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, setting `@type` is not quite easy in Winston, but it's possible to add a (kind of artificial) stacktrace to the message like:

```
format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format((info) => {
        if (info.level === 'error') {
            Object.assign(info, { message: `${info.message}${(new Error()).stack}` });
        }
        return info;
    })
...
)
```

That did the trick for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

I was just dealing with this in java, the key documentation is in [formatting requirements](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages?hl=en#formatting_requirements).

Quoting:

> Log entries in Logging that contain stack traces or exceptions, or that are formatted like ReportedErrorEvent, generate errors in Error Reporting.

Here's a related [bugfix](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback/issues/30) in a java library where they add a `@type` field with the value of `type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.ReportedErrorEvent` to the json log message object when severity is error.

I'm not sure the right way to do this in winston, but that's what you need to do.